# Does self-reference make the Peano-Russell system inconsistent?

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

//* Once again they want to lower a question with a piranha attack, putting negative scoring without giving reasons in the comments. Do it, it is clear that this is an illustrated Twitter, where only repetition of what is already known is allowed, with no room for innovation or creative questioning.

"Self reference is a semantic notion. Don't warry." But if it has been obtained using self-application? In that case it is a syntactic problem, and perhaps demonstrable in the PR system.

The formula satisfied by all formulas that are not self-applicable, and only by them, is self-applicable if and only if it is not self-applicable.

Because, if it is self-applicable, it is inconsistent with its definition, because it should be satisfied only by formulas that are not self-applicable.

And if it is not self-applicable then it should satisfy itself, so it would be self-applicable.

It is a syntactic paradox, therefore it should not be expressible in Peano-Russell.

But in principle, it would seem that it can be constructed:

NoAut(x): (y) ~Subst(x, y, num(y), #x)

¿Your feedback?

Note 1:
The definition of self-applicability can be formalized as follows:

Autap(x) <==>
<==> (Ey) Subst(x, y, num(y), #x)
&&
Proof(x)

But to be closer to Gödel's formalization, the Fixed Point theorem, or Diagonalization lemma, can be applied (Rudolf Carnap, 1934)

For every formula Z(x) with a single free variable, there exists a closed formula C, such that

|-- C <==> Z(#C)

Using it for self-application, C: Autap(#Autap(x)), Z: Proof(x):

|-- Autap(#Autap(x)) <==>
<==> Proof(#{Autap(#Autap(x)))})

The meaning is "this sentence is self-applicable."

Note 2:
There are three concepts involved in this topic:

1. Satisfaction: a subject satisfies its predicate, expressed in a formula, when the conditions expressed in the formula are met. It is a purely syntactic notion, and not relational, that is, it does not depend on its relationship with other formulas.
2. Demonstrability: a complete formula is demonstrable if there is a formal deduction from the logical axioms and those of the system, which has the formula in question as its last component. It is a syntactic notion as well, but it is relational; it depends not only on the conditions it expresses but also on its relationship with the axioms and the deduction rules used.
3. Truth: a statement (complete formula) is considered true if the formal system has a model, and it can be shown metamathematically that that statement corresponds to a true statement in the model. It is a **semantic** notion, much more complex and controversial than the previous ones.

In summary, to know if a subject satisfies its predicate, it is enough to follow the rules defined in the predicate, applying them to the subject. To know if it is demonstrable, we must find a deduction from the axioms. In the case of propositional logic there is at least one universal method (truth tables), but in first-order logic, although it is demonstrated (Gödel 1930, completeness theorem) that every logically valid statement is provable, there is no method to find that demonstration. In the case of systems with their own axioms, it is necessary to find the demonstration of the internal deduction of the system, the model, and the correspondence with some sentence of the same without the help of any general method.

In this particular case, to know if a formula is self-applicable, you have to find some argument that satisfies it. To know if a sentence is self-applied, it is enough to examine whether the argument is the Gödel number of the predicate.

Comment: What exactly is Subst here? Please note, that it's impossible to write an arithmetic formula saying "$y$ is godel number of formula that is true on $z$".

Comment: @mihaild Subst(x, y, z, #x) is the formula that calculates x by replacing the Gödel number of the free variable x, in the Gödel number of the fmla. y, by the number z. It is defined in the list of 36 recursive functions and relations in Gödel's original paper, and also in Eliott Mendelson, and other books that deal with the subject. I don't say "y is godel number of formula that is true on z" in any place. Satisfiable is not the same that true.

Comment: What is then "self-applicable formula" if not formula that is true on it's Godel number?

Comment: @mihaild
I edited the post to explain that issue.

Comment: Can you please write your definition of "self-applicatble formula"?

Comment: (I don't understand why your initila version was downvoted, but complains "I found a contradiction in well-known theory, but community censors it" certainly don't help; I, and probably many people here are willing to help you to understand - if that's what you want)

Comment: @mihaild
I edit the post for answer the question. The comment just above certainly doesn't help, except the trolls.

Comment: What is "Proof(x)" - is this formula saying "$x$ is Godel number of provable statement"? It's also not clear how you use fixed-point theorem - you can choose $Z$, but then theorem gives you $C$, you can't require it to be something specific.

Comment: @mihaild: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rPFce9wBQDp0F1ONUNqfPulwcccKCpju/view?usp=sharing page 210. "Proof(x)" is called here "Bew(x)", "x is the Gödel number of a provable formula".

Comment: So, closed formula is self-aplicable if it is a provable formula that can be written as $\phi(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)$, Is it so? (please note, that your link is access-protected, and anyway questions should be self-contained apart from references to easily-accessible sources)

Comment: @mihaild : Now the link is open. The answer to your question is in the cited paragraph of the book.
The question is self-contained for those who have the necessary background.

Comment: @mihaild: "So, closed formula is self-aplicable if it is a provable formula that can be written as ϕ(┌ϕ┐). Is it so?"
Its not that easy. If you instantiate an open formula of one variable by its own Gödel number, the argument is the Gödel number of an open formula, which is not the case.
You must have knowledge equivalent to that presented by Mendelson throughout the entire Chapter 3 (page 161 onwards).

Comment: Not very clear your formulas... following Godel's paper Subst(x, y, t) produce as output a *formula* taht is obtained from formula (coded) with x where we have replaced (free) variable y with *term* t.  Example with formula $(y=0)$ coded by x; if we consider term $1$, then Subst (x,y,1) will be $(y=0)[1/y]$ i.e. $(1=0)$.

Comment: You are writing instead Subst(x, y, num(y), #x) where num(y) is what? and #x is the code (G-number) of a formula? but x is already the code of formula...

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: (Expr 1) Subst(x, y, t) is a recursive function, defined **outside the formal system**.
While
(Expr 2) Subst(x, y, num(y), #x) is the formula within the formal system that **represents** the function defined in (Expr 1), because in the formal system the only functors or Function letters are f1, "+", and f2, "*", sum and product.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: num(y) is the Gödel number of the numeral containing the variable 'y'. #x is the Gödel number of the variable 'x', not of the content, but of the symbol itself, which is 21 in the original paper, but can vary depending on the presentation chosen. x, as an argument of (Expr 2) is the cod of a closed formula, obtained by replacing the free variable in y with its own cod.